# Show a different image based on presenting view controller and orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I present this view controller from several others. How can I present a different image based on

1. which view controller presented this one
2. the current interface orientation

Right now I have a button that opens above `ContextualController` with screen size image.
I want to call different images depending on where I pressed the button which I have in three different `UIViewControllers`.

From `UIViewController1` I want to call `context_1_landscape` and `context_1_portrait`. From `UIViewController2` I want to call `context_2_landscape` and `context_2_portrait`.

```
-(void) viewDidLoad;
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    

    if((self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft)||    (self.interfaceOrientation ==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)){
        UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"context_1_landscape.png"]];
        [self.view addSubview:imageview];
    } 
    else if ((self.interfaceOrientation ==UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)||(self.interfaceOrientation ==UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)){
        UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"context_1_portrait.png"]];
        [self.view addSubview:imageview];
    }
```

Comment: the question is how and where do I implement the if/only statement to make that work?

Comment: I am new to objective c :(

Answer (score 1):

You can find out who presented you by using the `presentingViewController` property of the `UIViewController`. My suggestion would be to have each of the presentingViewControllers have a property that is the image name (or the image itself) to be shown. Then in `viewDidLoad` you ask  the `presentingViewController` (cast to an object of the appropriate class) to supply the image to be used for portrait or landscape.

Comment: +1 That, or have each presenting controller set a property in `ContextualController` that tells it what image to use. It's no extra work, and it leaves the door open to letting the presenting controller select different images depending on circumstances.

Comment: thank you all for tips can you show an example if possible. i m kind of new at this